# fail2ban for apache2 doesn't seem to be working

Tags: apache-2.2, fail2ban

I have a lot of the following error messages in my apache error log:

```
[Thu Dec 16 15:13:24 2010] [error] [client 168.144.92.191] File does not exist: /var/www/mydomain/fud
[Thu Dec 16 15:13:24 2010] [error] [client 168.144.92.191] File does not exist: /var/www/mydomain/flag, referer: http://lexington.craigslist.org/fud/2076870022.html
[Thu Dec 16 15:14:28 2010] [error] [client 168.144.92.191] File does not exist: /var/www/mydomain/flag, referer: http://lexington.craigslist.org/fud/2115799176.html
[Thu Dec 16 15:17:51 2010] [error] [client 168.144.92.191] File does not exist: /var/www/mydomain/fud
```

In my **/etc/fail2ban/jail.local** I have:

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file.
#
# This file was composed for Debian systems from the original one
#  provided now under /usr/share/doc/fail2ban/examples/jail.conf
#  for additional examples.
#
# To avoid merges during upgrades DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE
# and rather provide your changes in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
#
# Author: Yaroslav O. Halchenko <debian@onerussian.com>
#
# $Revision: 281 $
#

# The DEFAULT allows a global definition of the options. They can be override
# in each jail afterwards.

[DEFAULT]

# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host
ignoreip = myip
bantime  = -1
maxretry = 3

# "backend" specifies the backend used to get files modification. Available
# options are "gamin", "polling" and "auto".
# yoh: For some reason Debian shipped python-gamin didn't work as expected
#      This issue left ToDo, so polling is default backend for now
backend = polling

#
# Destination email address used solely for the interpolations in
# jail.{conf,local} configuration files.
destemail = root@localhost

#
# ACTIONS
#

# Default banning action (e.g. iptables, iptables-new,
# iptables-multiport, shorewall, etc) It is used to define 
# action_* variables. Can be overriden globally or per 
# section within jail.local file
banaction = iptables-allports

# email action. Since 0.8.1 upstream fail2ban uses sendmail
# MTA for the mailing. Change mta configuration parameter to mail
# if you want to revert to conventional 'mail'.
mta = sendmail

# Default protocol
protocol = tcp

#
# Action shortcuts. To be used to define action parameter

# The simplest action to take: ban only
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report to the destemail.
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s]
              %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report and relevant log lines
# to the destemail.
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s]
               %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s]

# Choose default action.  To change, just override value of 'action' with the
# interpolation to the chosen action shortcut (e.g.  action_mw, action_mwl, etc) in jail.local
# globally (section [DEFAULT]) or per specific section 
action = %(action_mw)s

#
# JAILS
#

#
# HTTP servers
#

[apache]

enabled = true
port  = http,https
filter  = apache-auth
logpath = /var/log/apache2/error.log
maxretry = 3

# default action is now multiport, so apache-multiport jail was left
# for compatibility with previous (<0.7.6-2) releases
[apache-multiport]

enabled   = false
port    = http,https
filter    = apache-auth
logpath   = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry  = 6

[apache-noscript]

enabled = true
port    = http,https
filter  = apache-noscript
logpath = /var/log/apache2/error.log
maxretry = 3

[apache-overflows]

enabled = false
port    = http,https
filter  = apache-overflows
logpath = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 2
```

In my **/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-noscript.conf** I have:

```
failregex = [[]client <HOST>[]] (File does not exist|script not found or unable to stat): .*
failregex = [[]client <HOST>[]] script '.*' not found or unable to stat
```

My /var/log/fail2ban.log only has entries from when it was first started. Nothing mentioning IPs banned like my denyhosts.log does.

A check of "iptables -L -v -n" shows:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 834K packets, 145M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  403 71010 fail2ban-apache  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  403 71010 fail2ban-apache-noscript  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 574K packets, 976M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-apache (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  403 71010 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-apache-noscript (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  403 71010 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

What am I missing or what did I do wrong?

**** Post updated to show complete jail.local files instead of just Apache jail section and results of "iptables -L -v -n".**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the second line in apache-noscript.conf is nuking the first one.

Try this:

```
failregex = [[]client <HOST>[]] (File does not exist|script not found or unable to stat): .*
            [[]client <HOST>[]] script '.*' not found or unable to stat
```

Comment: Thank you Mikel. I have updated the filter as you described and will keep an eye on my iptales and the fail2ban.log.

Comment: Running "fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/error.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-noscript.conf" does confirm that your answer is correct. With my original settings, the last statement was the only one being check. However, I still am not getting IPs blocked by fail2ban. :/

Comment: Since making the change it now appears that everything is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a default `action` I'm missing, you have no `action` line. Here is mine (which works):

```
[apache-noscript]

enabled  = true
filter   = apache-noscript
action   = iptables-multiport[name=NoScript, port="http,https"]
logpath  = /usr/local/www/sites/*/logs/*_error_log
bantime  = 172800
maxretry = 5
```

I've simplified the match regex to 1 line:

```
failregex = [[]client <HOST>[]] (File does not exist|script not found or unable to stat)
```

Does `iptables -L -v -n` at least show that the chains are properly set up?

Comment: I have updated my original post to show my complete jail.local instead of just the apache-noscript jail. I have also included the output of the iptables command. As I understand it, my jail.local file is setup to have a default action of action_mw, which should ban and email me. I did notice that you have iptables-multiport while my file has iptables-allports. Could that possibly be the difference?

Comment: @KayakJim `iptables-allports` vs `iptables-multiport` shouldn't matter. All I can think of is turning up the logging. `fail2ban-client set 4`